# Accessing a variable from yml file in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to access a variable from an inventory file(yml) while running an ansible playbook. Snippet format of inventory file(only relevant section) looks like

```
        cfgs:
          - name: RCH
            members:
              -  holiday
              -  map
              -  list
              -  network
```

I am looking to import "RCH" as a variable in my playbook. Can someone please help me with this? and do not want to modify the inventory file as-well as this works for all other requirements.

I am able to access the whole section using "{{cfgs}}" which returns:

"“{'name': 'RCH', 'members': ['holiday', 'map', 'list', 'network']}“".

Also "{{cfgs['name']}}" or "{{cfgs["name"]}}" or "{{cfgs[1]}}" does not work when trying to extract "RCH" from the playbook.

Answer (score 1):

The `cfgs` variable is a list, and the first item in a list is at index `0`, not index `1`. So you would need:

```
"{{ cfgs[0] }}"
```

Some other examples:

```
"{{ cfgs[0].name }}"       # "RCH"
"{{ cfgs[0].members[3] }}" # "network"
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, this was exactly what i was looking for!!